# Input.mousePosition gives a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity

I'm trying to Add raycast shooting to my player but when I get the Vector2 mouse position it give this error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

This is my code

```
   Vector2 mousePosition = 
         new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x,
                     Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: You sure it's not Camera.main that's null?

Comment: sory i didnt understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Camera.main`](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/current/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) will be null if you don't have a camera in your scene with the tag `MainCamera`.

If you don't want to tag the camera, you can't use `Camera.main` but you can specify the `Camera` script you want to use. Something like:

```
GameObject cameraObject = GameObject.Find("MyCamera");
Camera myCamera = cameraObject.GetComponent<Camera>();
 Vector2 mousePosition =
                 new Vector2(myCamera .ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x,
                 myCamera .ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
```

Though, it's easier to just tag your main camera.

Comment: Sure. Remember to completely read your error messages. Further, it's super quick to attach the debugger and inspect your variables at run time, that'll give you a lot more flexibility to see what all the values are in your code and quickly debug issues like this.